# Adding flv/swf videos in html with video controls

Tags: html

How can i add flv/swf videos in html with video controls. Anyone ?

Answer (score 1):

probably you might work like this

```
 <script src="/Portals/0/includes/swfobject.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <object width="400" height="350" id="FLVPlayer" classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000">
 <param name="movie" value="http://www.RemoteServer.com/videos/FLVPlayer_Progressive.swf" />
 <param name="quality" value="high" />
 <param name="wmode" value="opaque" />
 <param name="scale" value="noscale" />
 <param name="salign" value="lt" />
 <param name="FlashVars" value="&amp;MM_ComponentVersion=1&amp;skinName=http://www.RemoteServer.com/videos/Corona_Skin_2&amp;streamName=http://www.RemoteServer.com/videos/OurVideo&amp;autoPlay=false&amp;autoRewind=false" />
 <param name="swfversion" value="8,0,0,0" />
 <!-- This param tag prompts users with Flash Player 6.0 r65 and higher to download the latest version of Flash Player. Delete it if you don’t want users to see the prompt. -->
 <param name="expressinstall" value="http://www.RemoteServer.com/videos/expressInstall.swf" />
  <!-- Next object tag is for non-IE browsers. So hide it from IE using IECC. -->
  <!--[if !IE]>-->
   <object width="400" height="350" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="http://www.RemoteServer.com/videos/FLVPlayer_Progressive.swf">
<!--<![endif]-->
<param name="quality" value="high" />
<param name="wmode" value="opaque" />
<param name="scale" value="noscale" />
<param name="salign" value="lt" />
<param name="FlashVars" value="&amp;MM_ComponentVersion=1&amp;skinName=http://www.RemoteServer.com/videos/Corona_Skin_2&amp;streamName=http://www.RemoteServer.com/videos/OurVideo&amp;autoPlay=false&amp;autoRewind=false" />
<param name="swfversion" value="8,0,0,0" />
<param name="expressinstall" value="http://www.RemoteServer.com/videos/expressInstall.swf" />
<!-- The browser displays the following alternative content for users with Flash Player 6.0 and older. -->
<div>
  <h4>Content on this page requires a newer version of Adobe Flash Player.</h4>
  <p><a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer"><img alt="Get Adobe Flash player" src="http://www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif" /></a></p>
</div>
  <!--[if !IE]>-->
</object>
   <!--<![endif]-->
  </object>
 <script type="text/javascript">
<!--
  swfobject.registerObject("FLVPlayer");
  //-->
  </script>
```

refer [1](http://www.adammer.com/blog/2009/07/how-to-add-flash-video-flv-with-controller-to-the-texthtml-module-in-dnn/) [2](http://www.templatemonster.com/help/how-to-embed-flv-video-into-html-page.html) [3](http://www.gromkov.com/faq/conversion/add_flash_video_to_website.html) [4](http://www.ehow.com/how_6881535_embed-flv-video-html.html)

Answer (score 0):

You need a player, there are some free ones out there, or you can write your own flash player.

Comment: How can i write my own player. Mr.phpalix , Explain in detail or else provide me an example?

Comment: https://www.google.com/#hl=en&safe=off&tbo=d&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=create+flash+player&oq=create+flash+player&gs_l=hp.3..0l4.500.3733.0.3892.19.16.0.2.2.1.362.3248.0j7j6j2.15.0.les%3B..0.0...1c.1.2.hp.Dx4_TSynGGc&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.41934586,d.Yms&fp=8388450ed71c4269&biw=1152&bih=699